# Parse HTTP response from fixer.io in node.js

Tags: google-cloud-functions, fixer.io

I am trying to do a http request to fixer.io to request some exchange rate data. This is the code I am using:

```
var url = "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=" + API + "&base=" + Currency + "&symbols=" + RequestCurrencies;

var request = require('request');

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("Data",body);
        console.log("Body",body.base);
```

The result in body looks good:

```
  {"success":true,"timestamp":1521058763,"base":"EUR","date":"2018-03-14","rates":{"USD":1.237167}}
```

But in body.base I just get "Body undefined".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you try the same request in a node script that you run locally on your own machine, does it work/behave differently?

Comment: It behaves the same, I just tried to run the code on repl.it..it is also undefined there

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I haven't parsed the JSON file. After adding this line it worked:

```
 var response = JSON.parse(body1);
```